# Flash builder error - namespace

Tags: air, flash-builder

I have some project files, in which I have changed the air version 1.0 to 2.5, because I have the air 2.5. But it is not compiling. It shows error that it cannot create air 
http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/2.5.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the AIR runtime you must also have

1. the [Air SDK (available here)](http://www.adobe.com/products/air/sdk/), or the new [Flex Hero SDK](http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/flexsdk/Download+Flex+Hero) (dev.) which is bound with air2.5
2. configure your compiler to use this
   new SKD to build your project.

Id suggest you to use the (currently latest) [Flex Hero SDK](http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/flexsdk/Download+Flex+Hero), which contains the air 2.5 runtime, so you don't have to bother merging your flex and new air sdks manually. 
Inside your IDE you specify a new Flex SDK to point to the Hero installation, and compile your project using this.